# How to stop an animation in GameQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gamequery

I have one image animation started using GameQuery. Now I want to stop the animation. For that, I have used the following code.

```
imgAnimation["myimage"] = new $.gameQuery.Animation({imageURL: imgPath + "test.png",  numberOfFrame: 3, delta: 130, rate: 236,
       type: $.gameQuery.ANIMATION_HORIZONTAL | $.gameQuery.ANIMATION_CALLBACK});

       $("#playground").playground({height: PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT, width: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH})
       .addGroup("actors", {width: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH, height: PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT})
       .addSprite("myimage",{animation: imgAnimation["myimage"],
       posx: imgXPos, posy: 0, width: 128, height: 384, callback: callbackAnimation})

       function callbackAnimation(){
         $("#myimage").stop();
         $("#myimage").clearQueue(); 
       }

       $.playground().startGame();
```

But this does not seem to be working. But at the same time, if I use the `hide()` method on the same animation element( `$("#myimage")` ), it works.

Both methods are part of the jQuery API only.

But why does the stop method not work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to give us some broader context - how do you animate $("#myimage") ?

Comment: I have edited the question with the proper code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this wasn't possible with version 0.5.x from gameQuery, but 0.6 is just out and add [pauseAnimation()](http://gamequeryjs.com/documentation/api/#pauseAnimation) and [resumeAnumation()](http://gamequeryjs.com/documentation/api/#resumeAnimation) that should do just what you want.